# Altbeacon NonBeaconLeScanCallback set setBackgroundScanPeriod?

Tags: android, bluetooth, altbeacon

I use Altbeacon NonBeaconLeScanCallback -> onNonBeaconLeScan() function to scan bluetooth devices which are not ibeacons.

```
@Override
    public void onNonBeaconLeScan(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice, int i, byte[] bytes) {
}
```

Is it possible to set scanning period for this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library is primarily designed for beacon detection, but it's scan cycling applies to non beacon detections, too.  It schedules scans at a configurable rate like this:

```
beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(...)
beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(...)
beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(...)
beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(...)
```

The parameters are in milliseconds.  The default for the foreground is 1100/0 and for the background 10000/300000

Note that on Android 8+ unless using a foreground service, the between scan period will be limited by the operating system to ~15 minutes.